# Iterate through aws workspaces using python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to print all the AWS Workspaces available in a specific region.

I have tried using  the code :

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('workspaces')
counter = client.describe_workspaces()
print counter()
```

But  "print counter()" is print a lot of values which I am not sure about, how can I store the Workspace ID in the "counter" variable so that I can iterate through them.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of IDs like this,

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('workspaces')

workspaces = client.describe_workspaces()['Workspaces']
workspaceIds = [workspace['WorkspaceId'] for workspace in workspaces]
```

Answer (score 0):

`WorkspaceID` is part of the response, all you need to do is iterate through the list returned. [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/workspaces.html#WorkSpaces.Client.describe_workspaces)

Answer (score 0):

You will get a nextToken guid to get the next N records.  I get 25 by default.  Keep going till you do not get that anymore.
Use ws_ids = [x['WorkspaceId'] for x in workspaces] to get the actual list of IDs and combine with your main list.